# Validation in ViewModel or in Database?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, validation, mvvm

I have an MVVM application where I'm switching from an XML to an SQL Server database (with EF).
Till now, all the validaiton logic was done in the ViewModel with the use of IDataErrorInfo and ErrorTemplates.

Now that I have a database with constraints and all the rest, I'm wondering which is the best place to put the validation logic: instinctively I'd let the database validate the data and eventually catch validation results from the repository, but I've never seen anyone do it.

Another question I have is: in the case I have validation in both VM and DB level, how can I prevent constraints misalignments?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: hi doctor, thank you for your answer. But 1 question: wouldn't it add the risk to have different constraints in code and database in case one is edited? Is it generally accepted?

Comment: EF is going to take the constraints from the database anyway if you create your model from the db. And if you do code first, it is your code that will put the referential constraints in place in the db.

Comment: you will want different constraints at both levels. eg i might want to be able to save an incomplete form for later completion even though the missing answers are invalid and should show red *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with most things it is down to preference but I think most would agree that safest option is to validate client side AND server side. Client side gives a nice user experience. Server side adds that extra security. Of course not all desktop apps will call through to a service but the principle still holds. Add validation for your users but revalidate in code before you save. There are so many ways to do this the implementation is up to you but that's the fun part.